# Counting how many chars of the alphabet are in a string

Tags: python, string, counter

I would like to count how many chars of the alphabet [a...z] are in a string, I don't care about "!" or "?" or "\n", ",", "." and many others. I just want the alphabet letters.

I was trying to use collections.Counter(string) but the problem is Counter is getting these unwanted chars and I don't know how to disconsider them.

And other problem is in my real idiom we use not only "o" but "ô" and "ó" as well as "e", "é", or "ç". In these cases these chars must considered.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use `collections.Counter`, then remove the elements that you don't care about.

Comment: Given a string for example `'aèîghk,l!;'lo'` what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: Should the counts of `ô` and `o` be combined or separate?

Comment: gmds: I think it doesn't matter because, lets consider banâná(writen wrong but...) the size of it will not change if you count a=1 â=1 and á=1. The sum will be the same.

Comment: cs95: Should be 9 I think. Should be considered only aèîghkllo I don't want ',!;

Comment: @Roger_88 Wait, so you just want the *total* count? So for `'banâná!!!'`, your expected result is 6?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the non-letters after you use `collections.Counter`.

```
import collections
import string

counter = collections.Counter(yourString)
for char in counter.keys():
    if not isalpha(char):
        del counter[char]
```

This will counter uppercase and lowercase letters separately, as well as letters that have different accents and diacritics. If you want to ignore case, you can use `collections.Counter(yourString.lower())`. If you also want to ignore diacritics, use `collections.Counter(yourString.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode().lower())`

Comment: Do you mean `char.isalpha()`?

Comment: This is on the right track but `we use not only "o" but "ô" and "ó" as well as "e", "é", or "ç". In these cases these chars must considered.` is not accounted for. Also, you may consider lowering the string. `Counter(text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode().lower())`

Comment: @cs95 I assumed `isalpha()` would be true for those characters.

Comment: Yes, but they will be counted as different characters, no?

Comment: @cs95 It is; `isalpha` returns `True` for all of them. In fact, the *opposite* problem exists; it will also accept, for example, characters from the CJK set. Whether they should be considered the same character is not clear from the OP, actually.

Comment: Actually, I don't know if "è" and "e" must be counted to be the same, or different characters. I think this is fine.

Comment: @cs95 I didn't think he wanted to combine their counts, he just wants to include them in the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to count unique characters, you can use set.intersection between the set of characters in your string, and a set of characters you accept:

maybe something like this:

```
import string

acceptable_chars = set('áàéíóúç').union(set(string.ascii_lowercase))
mystring = 'kfh;l1234sóúçids'
num_alpha = len(set(mystring.lower()).intersection(acceptable_chars))
print(num_alpha)
```

#### output :

```
10
```

Comment: But if mystring have á, à, é, í, ó, ú or even ç they will not be considered.

Comment: You probably need to build a set of the characters you can accept. See edit.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did: all the alphabet (lower case) `string.ascii_lowercase`, union the special characters you listed.

Answer (score 0):

**Given**

```
import string
import collections as ct


s = "Lorem ipsum çéó?"
```

**Code**

Make a set of `accepted` characters - exclude what you don't want; include what you do want.

```
excluded = set("oe")
included = set("ôóéç")
accepted = set(string.ascii_letters) - excluded | included
```

Count and mask the accepted characters.

```
counted = ct.Counter(s)
masked = ct.Counter(accepted)
shared = set((counted & masked).elements())
```

Filter accepted characters from Counter.

**Demo**

*Sum of characters*

```
sum(v for k, v in counted.items() if k in shared)
# 11
```

*Sum of unique characters*

```
sum(1 for k, _ in counted.items() if k in shared)
# 10
```

*Dict of tallied characters*

```
{k: v for k, v in counted.items() if k in shared}
# {'L': 1, 'r': 1, 'm': 2, 'i': 1, 'p': 1, 's': 1, 'u': 1, 'ç': 1, 'é': 1, 'ó': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, guys!

I marked the Reblochon Masque answer as right because I thought was right. But after test a little more I found out I was wrong. So I made my own solution based on his code.

The problem with that code is if my string is "kfh;l1234sóúçids" like his example, the output is correct, 10. But if I repteat it with spaces, like: "kfh;l1234sóúçids kfh;l1234sóúçids" I get 10 again and should be 20.

So, my solution is create a set of acceptable chars like his code and use it as reference.

Here:(In my case the output is 11 because I added a few more special chars to the set.

```
import collections
import string

# This counter is considering only acceptable_chars. All the rest is ignored.
def numChars(sentence):
    acceptable_chars = set('áàéíóúç').union(set(string.ascii_lowercase))
    chars = collections.Counter(sentence)
    acum = 0

    for key in acceptable_chars:
        if key in chars:
            acum += chars[key]

    return acum


x = numChars("kfh;l1234sóúçids")
print("Acum: " + str(x))
```

Output:

```
Acum: 11
```

If the string is 'kfh;l1234sóúçids \n kfh;l1234sóúçids':

```
Acum: 22
```